# Superscript plus sign meaning

Tags: theory, finite-automata, automata, state-machine, computation-theory

I have a quick question.
What does the superscript plus sign mean here?

= {w ∈ {0,1} : w ∈ (0^+)(1^+)}

Been awhile since I've done these. This is for making a non-deterministic finite automata

Comment: by the way, I this it is better practice to ask automata related questions in the computer science stack overflow community.

Answer (score 8):

```
0^+
```

this means that the string w should have atleast one 0, like { 0, 00, 000, .....}

on the other hand

```
0^*
```

this means that the string w can contain null character also, like { ∈, 0, 00, 000, ....}